# Can the iPhone Health App Log Numbers?

Tags: ios, health.app

I would like to keep track of how many abdominal crunches I can do. All the *Workout* Activity Types are based on *Calories* (some also *distance*) and the *Start* and *End* time.

Are there any *Workout* types or any other data types that fit my need to log just a number?

Maybe there are a third party app that can log special types to the Health App?

Comment: There's no way to add individual numbers to to the iPhone health app. There are dozens of apps that can log your excersize numbers to Health it, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by *Health it*. If the apps can log to the health data, so I can use the builtin Health app to e.g. plot the data - then that is what I am looking for.

Comment: Typo, should be HealthKit. The Health app will let you add individual data points to an existing activity but you can't add an individual exercise, like crunches. Your best bet is to download a free exercise app that let's you manually add your exercises and that can integrate with the Health app.